# Why i can't compile without declare a matrix like const

Tags: c, vector, matrix, constants

My doubt is: why in this code:

```
/*Asignacion de valores en arreglos bidimensionales*/
#include <stdio.h>

/*Prototipos de funciones*/
void imprimir_arreglo( const int a[2][3] );

/*Inicia la ejecucion del programa*/
int main()
{
  int arreglo1[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, 
                     { 4, 5, 6 } };                         
  int arreglo2[2][3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  int arreglo3[2][3] = { { 1, 2 }, { 4 } };

  printf( "Los valores en el arreglo 1 de 2 filas y 3 columnas son:\n" );
  imprimir_arreglo( arreglo1 );

  printf( "Los valores en el arreglo 2 de 2 filas y 3 columnas son:\n" );
  imprimir_arreglo( arreglo2 );

  printf( "Los valores en el arreglo 3 de 2 filas y 3 columnas son:\n" );
  imprimir_arreglo( arreglo3 );

  return 0;
}  /*Fin de main*/

/*Definiciones de funciones*/
void imprimir_arreglo( const int a[2][3] )
{
  int i;  /*Contador filas*/
  int j;  /*Contador columnas*/

  for (i = 0; i <=1; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
    {
      printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
    }

    printf( "\n" );
  }
} /*Fin de funcion imprime_arreglo*/
```

I can't compile without declaring the matrix variables like const, and in a vector i can... Why this behavior occurs? Sorry if my english its bad, i'm speak spanish. I'll be very thankful with your answers.

Comment: What? You mean on the function arguments? I think you can, what is the error?

Comment: My compiler tells me that i have to modify the type of the arrays but this behavior only occurs with a matrix and not in a vector, i want to know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a real mess about this subject. You should not use constant modifier for indirect pointers, like `const int**`, as there could be a mess, like:

1. Is it an `int **` that the values cannot be modified?
2. Or, is it a pointer (or even array) for `const int *`?

There is a [topic about it on C-faq](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html).

Example:

```
const int a = 10;
int *b;
const int **c = &b; /* should not be possible, gcc throw warning only */
*c = &a;
*b = 11;            /* changing the value of `a`! */
printf("%d\n", a);
```

It shouldn't allow to change `a`'s value, `gcc` does allow, and `clang` runs with warning but doesn't change the value.

Therefore, I'm not sure why the compilers (tried with `gcc` and `clang`) complain (with warnings, but works) about `const T[][x]`, as it is not *exactly* the same as above. But, in general, I may say that this kind of problem is solved on different ways depending on your compiler (as `gcc` and `clang`), so **never use `const T[][x]`** !

The best alternative, in my opinion, is to use a direct pointer:

```
void imprimir_arreglo( const int *a, int nrows, int ncols )
{
  int i;  /*Contador filas*/
  int j;  /*Contador columnas*/

  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
    {
      printf( "%d ", *(a + i * ncols + j) );
    }

    printf( "\n" );
  }
}
```

And to call:

```
imprimir_arreglo( arreglo1[0], 2, 3 );
```

This way, your function is more dynamic and more portable.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer but i want to know why that behavior occurs??

Comment: @ChristianCisneros, I tried to explain on a superficial way, but perhaps I couldn't. Try reading the very same discussion on GCC's bugzilla [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20230) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16895).

Comment: Ok @MatheusOI thank you for your great answer i'll read the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Remove const from

```
void imprimir_arreglo( const int a[2][3] );
```

and

```
void imprimir_arreglo( const int a[2][3] )
{
```

and your code will work.

Comment: I know that @Armin but my doubt is why that behavior only occurs in a matrix and not in a vector?

Comment: @ChristianCisneros As far as i know [c] does not have vectors. If you,re using a special library you should mention it.

Comment: The vector is an array of only one subindex and a matrix is an array of multiple subindex as far as i know